# SSH failed with too many authentication failure only when running from nohup demon background

Tags: ssh

I have the below script, which runs a ssh command in remote unix server and store the output in a variable and print that variable.

The script runs fine when I run in foreground or with (`nohup ./script &`) in background as long the session is active, but when I am exiting from that session the script fails with staging "Too may authentication failure".

I have checked `ps -ef | grep script` , which was showing the background process was assigned to terminal /dev/pts1 and now it's showing "?" which is a demon process.

I have checked with ssh -n or -f option but ended with same problem.
Please note that , the SSH command runs with auto password.

Script: (i run the command as `nohup ./script.sh > script.log 2>&1 &`)

```
#!/usr/bin/ksh
while ture;
do    
x=`ssh username@remote_server "ls -l /dir1/dir2/*|wc -l"`    
echo "the count is $x"    
sleep 2m    
done
```

After this I tried to capture with ssh -v option and please find the below output for the failed one.
I found that it is saying /dev/tty is not found and i guess it is because there is no terminal as it is assigned to demon process as we have killed the session from where the nohup & was run.

```
debug1: Host 'username' is known and matches the DSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/.ssh/known_hosts:15
debug1: rekey after 4294967296 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: rekey after 4294967296 blocks
debug1: pubkey_prepare: ssh_get_authentication_socket: No such file or directory
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512>
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password,keyboard-interactive
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /home/.ssh/id_rsa --------here it was like Offering RSA public key: local_user_name
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password,keyboard-interactive
debug1: Trying private key: /home/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password,keyboard-interactive
debug1: Trying private key: /home/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: Next authentication method: keyboard-interactive
debug1: read_passphrase: can't open /dev/tty: No such device or address
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password,keyboard-interactive
debug1: read_passphrase: can't open /dev/tty: No such device or address
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password,keyboard-interactive
debug1: read_passphrase: can't open /dev/tty: No such device or address
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password,keyboard-interactive
debug1: Next authentication method: password
debug1: read_passphrase: can't open /dev/tty: No such device or address
Received disconnect from remote_IP_address:2: Too many authentication failures
Authentication failed.
```

edited here as requested for successful log:

```
nohup: ignoring input
OpenSSH_7.4p1, OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips 11 Feb 2013
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 58: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to remote_server [remoteserver_ip] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.4
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_7.2
debug1: match: OpenSSH_7.2 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug1: Authenticating to remote_server:22 as 'remote_server_user'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ssh-dss
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: aes128-ctr MAC: hmac-sha1 compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: aes128-ctr MAC: hmac-sha1 compression: none
debug1: kex: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org need=20 dh_need=20
debug1: kex: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org need=20 dh_need=20
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ssh-dss SHA256some_key_goes_here
debug1: Host 'remote_server' is known and matches the DSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/.ssh/known_hosts:15
debug1: rekey after 4294967296 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: rekey after 4294967296 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512>
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password,keyboard-interactive
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: MY_user_id
debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg rsa-sha2-512 blen 533
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
Authenticated to remote_server ([remote_server_ip]:22).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: pledge: network
debug1: client_input_global_request: rtype hostkeys-00@openssh.com want_reply 0
debug1: Sending environment.
debug1: Sending env LANG = C
debug1: Sending command: MY COMMAND HERE
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype exit-status reply 0
debug1: channel 0: free: client-session, nchannels 1
debug1: fd 0 clearing O_NONBLOCK
debug1: fd 1 clearing O_NONBLOCK
debug1: fd 2 clearing O_NONBLOCK
Transferred: sent 3784, received 2544 bytes, in 0.1 seconds
Bytes per second: sent 37022.5, received 24890.4
debug1: Exit status 0
```

Please let me know how to fix this issue.
Please let me know if you need more information to provide a solution for this issue.
Local server: GNU Linux

Remote server: sun solaris

Comment: Since this is about authentication failures, may I ask what mechanism you are using to authenticate *when it works*.  Are you using a key agent, or SSH agent forwarding?  It sounds like the script is losing access to the agent when you log out.  Can you [edit] your question to include the authentication mechanism you are using?

Comment: Generating an identity file and using `ssh -i` and the `-n` flag would be my approach to the solving the problem.  You will need to put the identity file public key in your `authorized_keys` file on the remote server.

Comment: long live couling and others for your continuous support. Couling , I have edited the question with the successful log. Kindly have a look.

Comment: my username has a public key and i connect to ITGATE unix box and from there I logged in to a generic username@local_servername by selecting the menu. And there I actually run the nohup ./script.sh & , and I think it is working coz it it taking the public key authentication of the very initial login( my own user and public key).But post exiting from the session may be that connection is not happening.Please let me know if i would change anything that ssh command line if i have to hardcode any username or credential or any better way.It is companys production data.SoI dont want to play with it.